# Android- JavaNullPointer on addContentView

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

### I can't set a contentView:

How can i do a better job with this code, i was  trying with asyncTask class but return the same error.

> The code exit with error: JavaNullPointer  on This line 
>   addContentView(surface, new
>   ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

```
private SurfaceView cameraView;
private String barcodeInfo;
private CameraSource cameraSource;
private Renderer renderer;
private RajawaliSurfaceView surface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
    //barcodeInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoTextView);

    BarcodeDetector detector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE).build();
    cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, detector).setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480).build();

    cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("CAMERA SOURCE", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            cameraSource.stop();
        }
    });

    detector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {

        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            release();
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (barcodes.size() == 1) {

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        muestraMono();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
public void muestraMono(){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RajawaliSurfaceView surface = new RajawaliSurfaceView(this);
    surface.setFrameRate(60.0);
    surface.setRenderMode(IRajawaliSurface.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    surface.setTransparent(true);
    addContentView(surface, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    renderer = new Renderer(this);
    surface.setSurfaceRenderer(renderer);
}
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       Process: com.dsinteg.lectorqr, PID: 2822
>                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                           at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.onResume(GLSurfaceView.java:567)
>                                                                           at
>   org.rajawali3d.surface.RajawaliSurfaceView.onResume(RajawaliSurfaceView.java:106)
>                                                                           at
>   org.rajawali3d.surface.RajawaliSurfaceView.onAttachedToWindow(RajawaliSurfaceView.java:125)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:12618)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3621)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3435)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3411)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.addContentView(PhoneWindow.java:321)
>                                                                           at android.app.Activity.addContentView(Activity.java:2016)
>                                                                           at com.dsinteg.lectorqr.MainActivity.muestraMono(MainActivity.java:93)
>                                                                           at com.dsinteg.lectorqr.MainActivity$2$1.run(MainActivity.java:81)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
>                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Nullpointer Exception Error in Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911934/android-nullpointer-exception-error-in-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
getWindow().addContentView(surface, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Error is happening because, the activity does not know the parent.

Comment: still not working git getWindow. public method muestraMono() work in this section :
//-------------------------------------
//------------------------------------- 
But not in the actual section receiveDetections

Answer (score 0):

`SetContentView` will overwrite the layout, and replace it with a new one. Usually, you only want to do this once in `onCreate`. You could do it more, but it involves re-drawing the entire layout, So try removing this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

From your `muestraMono` method.

**Update**

Create method like this

```
public void muestraMono(){
    surface = new RajawaliSurfaceView(this); // make RajawaliSurfaceView a class variable
    surface.setFrameRate(60.0);
    surface.setRenderMode(IRajawaliSurface.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    surface.setTransparent(true);
    addContentView(surface, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    renderer = new Renderer(this);
    surface.setSurfaceRenderer(renderer);
}
```

Then call this in `onCreate` once and again call this method after you scan the QR Code

Comment: and what if you call this method directly in `onCreate` method below `setContentView`?

Comment: the method work if I call in onCreate but I want call the method only if my app scann a QR code

Comment: Same error in addContentView. I get good work in onCreate but the error still here:
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        muestraMono();
                    }
                });

Comment: are you sure it has to be ActionBar.LayoutParams... Check that and have you done same as my update ?

Comment: I have the same code on monoMuestra like your update....... well i'm new on this for what can i change this : new ActionBar.LayoutParams if it is not correct?

Comment: @FernandoGonzález is your `Renderer` class properly  implementing IRajawaliSurfaceRenderer

Comment: Yes because I can render a Blender Model with some textures .... the app crash when the QR code is scanned ......